# Como adicionar usuário em um grupo no Django utilizando CBV?

Tags: python, django

Estou usando CBV para meus cadastros, e tenho a seguinte classe para a criação de usuários no meu projeto:

**forms.py**

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name']

    def save.... (Não sei aqui)
```

**views.py**

```py
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin

class SignUpView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'auth/register.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('sign-in')
    form_class = UserRegisterForm
    success_message = "Your profile was created successfully"
```

Através do Django Admin, criei um grupo chamado **readonly**, e o que quero fazer é o seguinte:

Toda vez que adicionar um usuário, este usuário deve ser adicionado nesse grupo **readonly**.

Sei que preciso alterar algo na classe **UserRegisterForm** no metodo **save**, mas não tenho ideia como fazer. Alguem pode me ajudar? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Adicione o grupo dentro do `form_valid`. Algo conforme abaixo:

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name']


    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Adiciona o grupo ao form aqui...
        form.cleaned_data['grupo'] = <GRUPO>  # Veja nota
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**nota**:  deverá ser substituído pelo nome do grupo **OU** pela instância do grupo **OU** pelo ID do grupo **OU**... Depende de como está no models.

**Atualização em 2/10/2021**

form.cleaned_data retorna um dicionário dos campos do formulário após sua validação

**fim da atualização**

Perceba que ao chamar o `super()...` o `save()` será automaticamente realizado. Veja [aqui](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/)

Comment: O que seria esse cleaned_data?

Comment: Atualizei o post informando sobre o cleaned_data

Comment: Para quem votou negativo, favor dizer o motivo, para que eu melhore a resposta.